# Determining the suitable cms

Tags: web, content-management-system, e-commerce

I'm developing an e-commerce community website, and i'm not sure which cms to use.

Here are more specific details:

1. It has to be themable, as i'm not a designer, with plenty of high quality templates online. (Wordpress, joomla and drupal are good examples of this).
2. It has to have a good e-commerce plugin. (I'm leaning towards virtuemart plugin for joomla)
3. It has to have a good forum plugin. (I'm leaning towards kunena plugin for joomla)
4. Very easy to use, with minimal coding, as my development partners are not not programmers (Its more of a hobby project). (Wordpress is the king here no doubt, only some css editing required to adjust a template).

My current choice is joomla with virtue mart and kunena. I think it has a very good combination of functionality, ease of use and plenty of high quality themes.

Is there a better choice ?

Please mention pros and cons of your choice and the amount of coding required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which CMS to choose? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490899/which-cms-to-choose)

Comment: @meager - distinctly different.

Comment: @meager - my requirements are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make this decision once - and I chose Drupal.

My decision was influenced by the need for Internationalization in addition to what you listed
; however, a couple years later, and having used Joomla in mean time, I still think Drupal is the way to go. Here's why:

1. Ubercart is a great open source e-commerce module and is widely used with solid group of forum goers. This is especially useful because there is more abstraction in E-Commerce plugins than plugins in general - so you may need help somewhere.
2. Drupal has a built in Forum system that is easy to use and fairly customizable. It isn't as full featured as some, but there are 3rd party modules for that.
3. Drupal's Administration: Maybe it's because I have more experience in Drupal, but Joomla's administration is just clunky. It lacks intuition and documentation.
4. Joomla is more Object Oriented - which makes some of the design harder to grasp if you're not a programmer. To extend/change a Drupal Module is much easier.
5. I would say they are about equal in terms of Themes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing a new site on your own and you want to get it done quickly and done well, then the answer is: write it using the tools you already know. (if you know more than one already then you should already have a good feel for which one would suit this project the best)

If you have the luxury of having enough slack time on your project to learn a new system then the best answer is to use some of that time doing some evaluation on a few systems. Spend time putting together a simple prototype site in each of them. All the major CMSs are capable of doing what you want, but you may find one easier to work with than another, or that a particular one has a specific way of doing things that you like. A lot of it is very much person preference and can only really be found out by trying them out.

Finally, you say you want minimal coding. Fair enough. Don't expect to have zero coding though. So therefore you should probably pick one that is written in a language that you're comfortable with.